# alternative implementation of java.util.function.Function in java 7

Tags: scala, java-8, java-7

I'm trying to rebuild the GeoMesa source code under jdk 1.7 and scala 2.10. But it uses the new features in java 8, like the "java.util.function.Function" in the code below. Is there any alternative way to replace such function in java 8?

```
/**
    * Gets table names and converters for each table (e.g. index) that supports the sft\n
    *
    * @param sft simple feature type
    * @param ds data store
    * @param indices indices to write/delete
    * @return (table names, write converters, remove converters)
    */ 

def getTablesAndConverters[DS <: GeoMesaDataStore[DS, F, W], F<:WrappedFeature,W] (
      sft: SimpleFeatureType,
      ds: DS,
      indices: Option[Seq[GeoMesaFeatureIndex[DS, F, W]]] = None): (IndexedSeq[String], IndexedSeq[(F) => Seq[W]], IndexedSeq[(F) => Seq[W]]) = {

    val toWrite = indices.getOrElse(ds.manager.indices(sft, IndexMode.Write)).toIndexedSeq

    val key = s"${ds.config.catalog};${CacheKeyGenerator.cacheKey(sft)};${toWrite.map(_.identifier).mkString(",")}"
    val load = new java.util.function.Function[String, (IndexedSeq[String], IndexedSeq[(Any) => Seq[Any]], IndexedSeq[(Any) => Seq[Any]])] {
      override def apply(ignored: String): (IndexedSeq[String], IndexedSeq[(Any) => Seq[Any]], IndexedSeq[(Any) => Seq[Any]]) = {
        val tables = toWrite.map(_.getTableName(sft.getTypeName, ds))
        val writers = toWrite.map(_.writer(sft, ds))
        val removers = toWrite.map(_.remover(sft, ds))
        (tables, writers.asInstanceOf[IndexedSeq[(Any) => Seq[Any]]], removers.asInstanceOf[IndexedSeq[(Any) => Seq[Any]]])
      }
    }

    converterCache.get(key, load).asInstanceOf[(IndexedSeq[String], IndexedSeq[(F) => Seq[W]], IndexedSeq[(F) => Seq[W]])]
  }
```

Comment: There is a [project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) that, among other things, backported all of the `java.util.function` interfaces in a different package (obviously without the default and static methods). It'd propably be overkill to include the whole jar but you could use the source and just include that package.